# Exceptions not catching using catch block. Why?

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

So I have made use of a few try/catch blocks during my first project learning C#.  For the most part, they have worked fine.  However, there are a couple where the code still breaks at the point of an exception despite the fact it is finding the exact exception type I was anticipating and hoping for.  I'll provide an example of code where this issue occurs.

**Here is where I try to catch the exception:**

```cs
app.MoveFolder(input1, input2);

try {
    //code here
} catch (ArgumentException) {
    //code here
}
break;
```

**Here is the function where I create the exception:**

```cs
public void MoveFolder(string folderPath, string newLocation) {
    this.ThrowExceptionIfFolderDoesntExist(folderPath);

    if (Directory.Exists(newLocation) == true) {
        throw new ArgumentException("example");
    }
    Directory.Move(folderPath, newLocation);
}
```

**The `ThrowExceptionIfFolderDoesntExist()` function leads to this:**

```cs
private void ThrowExceptionIfFolderDoesntExist(string folderPath) {
    if (this.CheckFolderExists(folderPath) == false) {
        throw new ArgumentException("This folder does not exist");
    }
}
```

**So, as you can see, both this and the if statement in my `MoveFolder()` function should return `ArgumentExceptions` which I was hoping to catch.  In the case of the latter function, this works as intended.  However, if I try to move a folder to a location that already exists, then I get the following:**

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: example
```

This is not what I'm wanting, as I want the catch block to handle this particular ArgumentException also. Is this something to do with the catch block thinking I am referring to a specific argument exception?  I would have thought it would refer to all ArgumentExceptions.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Well, the call to MoveFolder is not inside the try block, why do you expect to catch the exception?

Comment: the thing that is throwing the exception (MoveFolder) exists outside the try catch block.  move app.MoveFolder(input1, input2) inside the try block

Comment: `app.MoveFolder(input1, input2);
` needs to be inside the `try`...  Where your first `//code here` comment is

Comment: Feeling a bit silly now!  I thought it would have worked the way I had it because I was thinking in terms of 1) run method 2) one of these two things will result (try/catch).  Cheers guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to do a proper try/catch, you need to do the following:

1. Place your method in the `try` block
2. `catch` the `Exception(s)`
3. `throw` the `Exception`

Here is some code

```
try
{
    app.MoveFolder(input1, input2);
}
// catch ArgumentException
catch(ArgumentException ex)
{
    throw;
}
// catch all others
catch(Exception ex)
{
    throw;
}
```

Comment: this way the Stacktrace and possible inner exceptions are getting lost. If you intend to just throw the exception on the next level just use `throw` without creating a new exception

Comment: Aha! for some reason I'd decided to put functions outside of the catch block because I thought it had to run the function first so that the exception would show up BEFORE it reached either the try or catch.  This answers my question nicely, many thanks!

Comment: @jamessct Glad to help.

Comment: If you're going to rethrow the exception, it's better to use `throw;` to preserve the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

In order to catch an exception thrown by a function, the function needs to be called in the Try {}. You can do as the others said and call the MoveFolder inside a Try Block. If you throw an exception outside of the Try Block, it can sometimes be picked up by other catch blocks, or just unhandled and creates an error.

```cs
try {
    app.MoveFolder(Something1, Something2);
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    //Do something with Exception
}
```

Comment: I selected the other answer as he got there first, but cheers this answered my question :)